# Things we should take care of when we operate multiple Spring Integration flow together

Tags: spring-integration

What would be the important thing we should take care of when we would like to use many spring integration workflows together in a system?

As I know:
- channel id-s should be unique (so two cannot have the same channel id)

- aggregations should connect to message stores with different region

Am I correct? Are there any bulletpoints?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Other points to keep in mind are:

1. `errorChannel` is global bean for entire `ApplicationContext`
2. You should think about different `TaskExecutor` and `TaskScheduler` do not impact different flows
3. You can take a look to the [Spring Integration Flow](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-flow) Extension
4. You can study MicroServices using [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)

All other things should be OK for any complex application. Although I'd prefere to differentiate such tasks by different simple applications - MicroServices